# Why does it take longer to toggle graphics after a selection is made from a combo box?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, mvvm, profiling

I have a WPF app that draws a compass. There is a large ring with tick marks and labels. I have a checkbox that toggles the compass graphics on and off. When I first start up the app, the compass turns on and off instantly.

Meanwhile, I have a combo box that grabs some data from a local database and uses that to render some overlay graphics. After using this combo box, the compass graphics no longer toggle quickly. In fact, the UI completely freezes for about 4 seconds whenever I click the checkbox.

I attempted to profile my app using Window Performance Profiling Tool for WPF. When I activated the checkbox, not only did my app freeze, so did the profiler. The graphs "catched up" afterward, but this tells me something must be seriously wrong.

I've managed to nail down that the problem graphics are the tick marks (not the numeric labels). If I eliminate them, the freezing problem stops. If I cut them down from 360 to, say, 36, the app still freezes, but for less time. Again, no matter how many tick marks I have, they toggle instantly when the app first starts.

My question is, **How do I figure out why the toggle for my compass graphics goes from instant to horribly slow?** I've tried extensive profiling and debugging, and I just can't come up with any reason why setting the Visibility on some tick marks should ever cause the app to freeze.

**Edit**

Okay, I've stripped everything out of my app to just the bare essentials, zipped it up, and uploaded it to Sendspace. Here is the link (it's about 143K):

http://www.sendspace.com/file/n1u3yg

[**Note:** don't accidentally click the banner ad, the real download link is much smaller and lower on the page.]

Two requests:

1. **Do you experience the problem on your machine?** Try opening Compass.exe (in bin\Release) and clicking the check box rapidly. The compass tick marks should turn on and off with no delay. Then, select an item from the combo box and try rapidly clicking the check box again. On my machine, it's very laggy, and after I stop rapid-fire clicking, it takes a few seconds for the graphics to catch up.
2. If you do experience the lag, **do you see anything in the code that could be causing this odd behavior?** The combo box is not connected to anything, so why should selecting an item from it affect the future performance of other graphics on the window?

Comment: I think you should upload code if you want an answer

Comment: but didn't you find the perfromance bottle-neck?

Comment: @Tigran, only sort of. I know that the tick marks are a bottleneck, but I don't know why they are sometimes not a bottleneck. What I'm trying to figure out is what conditions cause them to become an issue.

Comment: Also, the freeze is just as bad when I hide them as when I show them.

Comment: Whenever you have an infinite loop, or one that runs way too long, just pause it once in the IDE and see what it's doing, because you know it's in the loop.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey, I've tried that numerous times. All my code seems to finish quickly and w/o any infinite loops. The delay occurs during WPF layout/rendering. I can't observe why the rendering for the exact same graphics is sometimes instant and sometimes slow.

Comment: @DanM: OK, I guess I'm out of my depth. Let's see if there are any WPF experts.

Comment: Do you have lots of event handling? A common mistake is to add handlers multiple times (on button clicks) rather than just once (on the creator) for example.

Comment: @DanM: What ChrisF says, I've seen myself. It's super easy to attach many many copies of the same event handler, so instead of handling the event once, you handle it N times. If this is a paint event, it will cost you big time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although ANTS didn't indicate a particular performance 'hotspot', I think that your technique is slightly flawed as it seems that every tick has a `ViewModel` that is responsible for handling an individual tick, and you are individually binding those ticks to the view. You end up creating 720 view models for these ticks that fire the a similar event each time the entire compass is shown or hidden. You also create a new LineGeometry every time this field is accessed.

The recommended approach for WPF in a custom drawn situation like this is to use a `DrawingVisual` and embrace the retained mode aspect of WPF's rendering system. There are several googleable resources that talk about this technique, but the gist is to declare a compass class inherits from `FrameworkElement`, and some smaller classes that inherit from `DrawingVisual` and use that to render the compass. With this technique, you can still have a ViewModel drive the compass behavior, but you wouldn't have individual viewmodels for each part of the compass. I'd be inclined to decompose the compass into parts such as bezel, arrow, sight, etc... but your problem may require a different approach.

```
class Compass : FrameworkElement
{
    private readonly List<ICompassPart> _children = new List<ICompassPart>();

    public void AddVisualChild(ICompassPart currentObject)
    {
        _children.Add(currentObject);
        AddVisualChild((Visual)currentObject);
    }

    override protected int VisualChildrenCount { get { return _children.Count; } }

    override protected Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= _children.Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return _children[index] as Visual;
    }

    override protected void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        //The control automatically renders its children based on their RenderContext.
        //There's really nothing to do here.
        dc.DrawRectangle(Background, null, new Rect(RenderSize));
    }
}

class Bezel : DrawingVisual
{
   private bool _visible;

   public bool Visible {
   {
     get { return _visible; }
     set
     {
        _visible = value;
        Update();
     }
   }

   private void Update()
   {
       var dc = this.RenderOpen().DrawingContext;
       dc.DrawLine(/*blah*/);
       dc.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ritch. +1 and thank you for taking the time to look at my code sample and write up your answer. I do have a couple questions/comments. First, I only seem to be creating 360 view models, not 720. At least, I've verified that the constructor is only called 360 times. Can you explain where you are seeing 720 view models? Second, I thought I *wasn't* creating a new line geometry each time, but only the first time the ticks are drawn. In fact, if I put a break point in the `public Geometry Geometry` property getter, it only gets hit once for the entire lifetime of the app.

Comment: (continued) Finally, while your answer may very well bypass the problem I'm having altogether, it doesn't directly answer my question, which is: Do you experience a slowdown *only* after selecting an item from the drop-down and if so, why? Even if I should be using a VisualHost and DrawingVisual (and I will definitely consider switching to this technique), why does performance become slow only after manipulating a seemingly unrelated combo box?

Comment: Followup: I just tried keeping the code as is except for toggling the whole CompassLayer rather than the individual tick marks. This seems to get rid of any noticeable delay after using the combo box. I still cannot explain the role of the combo box, however.

Comment: Final item: I can't seem to find any documentation for the `VisualHost` class on MSDN. Is this definitely the name of the class?

Comment: @DanM - For the 720 calls, put a Debug.Trace line and a static counter on the Geometry property (which is I mentioned the duplicate creation, obviously don't cache unless you need to do so, but this seems like one of those cases [if you stay with this technique]). I saw it in ANTS first, then I measured it by tracing. I don't see a performance difference between the two cases.

Comment: @DanM - No, sorry. That was a brain-fart, `VisualHost` should be `FrameworkElement`

Comment: @DanM - Here's Petzold on the matter. The sample is a bit complex, but it makes the argument for `DrawingVisual` quite well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx

Comment: Ritch, thanks for the follow-up. I think what's happening with the view models is that 360 are being created, but the binding engine is accessing each one twice, making it appear as if there are 720. Anyway, I agree about caching the Geometry data, and thanks for the link to the Petzold article--very enlightening. One last note: interesting that you are not seeing the performance difference between the two cases. I wonder if I'm experiencing some sort of video card issue on my machine.

Comment: Ritch (last comment, I promise :)). Just wanted to let you know that I incorporated the "drawing visuals" technique into my app, and updates have gone from 1 or more seconds to instantaneous. Amazing. It was a breeze to make the conversion too. I had a couple of ItemsControls that I changed to custom FrameworkElement classes, and I was pretty much done. Thanks again for pointing me to this technique.

Comment: @DanM - Yea, I'm a big fan of it.